# Which is the correct usage?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, past-tense

Which is the correct usage?

```
 1. I don't know how did it go wrong.
 2. I don't know how it went wrong.
```

Similarly it happen in the following cases also

```
 1. He doesn't know where she is.
 2. He doesn't know where is she.
```

Is there any alternate way to express the same?

Comment: Neither of those are questions. You might be interested in our sister site: [ell.se].

Comment: @MattЭллен please see my edit. It was a mistake

Comment: As Matt said, neither is correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach could you suggest a correct way?

Comment: @noufal What are you trying to express? Given that they both end in question marks, neither is correct usage.

Comment: It's not clear whether you intend to ask a question or make a statement. And your second set is wrong too (he ***doesn't*** know). It does appear that your questions would be a better fit for ELL.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Actually I intended to make a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is ungrammatical. The second is grammatical, but the question mark should be replaced with a full stop.